# sorting list of objects python

Tags: python, sorting

I wrote a class that stores a list of objects which I have also defined.

I would like to be able to call `obj_list.sort()`, and have the results sorted in ascending order, but it isn't working out exactly how I want it.

If I get the `obj` data and call `sort()` three times this is the behavior with my current implementation:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj_list = self.set_obj_list()

    def set_obj_list(self):
        data = []
        for x in range(20):
            obj = MyObjClass(x)
            data.append( obj )

        data.sort()
        return data

class MyObjClass():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number # number is an integer

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.number, other.number)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.number)

a = MyClass()
print a.obj_list
a.obj_list.sort()
print a.obj_list
a.obj_list.sort()
print a.obj_list
a.obj_list.sort()
print a.obj_list
```

Thank you.

I want it sorted in ascending order, but for `sort()` to do nothing if already sorted.

Comment: You have to implement [`__cmp__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__).

Comment: are you calling `list.sort` or your own sort method?

Comment: I modified the set_obj_list() function to represent what I want done.

Comment: is the output in your question what you expect or what you are trying to avoid?

Comment: Changed for clarity.  I want it to sort left to right.  Currently it is doing what is shown in my example.

Comment: Please provide code that actually produces the output you're seeing. `.. loop something ..` is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: @Kevin if you cannot understand what is happening from this code then just don't post.  It's pretty much obvious that I'm appending objects to a list.  I'm not going to post the thousands of lines of code that I have for these objects and their instantiation.

Comment: @Matt if you can't post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then don't ask a question.

Comment: @AdamSmith That is what this is.  You people are ridiculous.  Inserted a single line of code.

Comment: @Matt your code as originally posted can not reproduce your example, therefore it might be Minimal, but was neither Complete nor Verifiable.

Comment: @AdamSmith Actually it does if you instantiate `MyClass` and `<instance>.obj_list.sort()` multiple times.  You shouldn't have to do that to answer this question.  As demonstrated by the answer-er.

Comment: @Matt your originally posted code would raise a `SyntaxError`. Although it certainly would produce an error, my guess is that it's not the problem you were having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__lt__` should return a true value if & only if `self` is less than `other`, but `cmp(self, other)` will return a true value (1 or -1) if `self` does not equal `other`.  You need to change this:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return cmp(self.number, other.number)
```

to this:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return cmp(self.number, other.number) < 0
```